# Call JS package as npm script into another package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a package **Package2** that depends on **Package1**.

**Package 1**:
consists of the following files (for this example)

```
      package.json
      index.js
      /bin/package1 (no extension)
```

**Package 1** package.json:

```js
      ...
      {
      "name": "package1",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "description": "a JavaScript library that should be called by other stuff",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "bin": "cli.js"
      },
      ...
```

**Package 1** /bin/package1 script:

```js
      #!/usr/bin/env node
      const package1 = require('../'); 
      // just import the package1 module an it should run  without function call
```

**Package 2**  is a package that depends on package1.

**Package 2**  package.json:

```js
      ...
      "name": "package2",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "a JavaScript library that depends on package1",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "serve" : "package1 ."
      },
      ...
```

But I'm getting an error when I run `yarn serve`:

```sh
yarn run v1.22.17
$ package1 .
'package1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've tried a lol of different things, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried to add the **.js** extension to **/bin/package1**?

Comment: yes my initial test was with the *.js* extension, after inspecting the source code of other packages working as expected they weren't using it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this after the "scripts" tag into **package 1**'s package.json:

```js
    ...
    "scripts": {....},
    "bin": {
        "package1": "bin/package1"
      },
    ...
```

and that's it